# How to connect database in php file?

Tags: 7, database

I have a custom module and in this module I've a `.php` file and inside this file I need to insert the data into database. I am using below code:

```
  define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '../includes/bootstrap.inc';

  include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '../includes/database.inc';
  include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '../includes/database.mysql.inc';
  conf_init();
  drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_CONFIGURATION);
  drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE);
  $userid = $_POST['user'];
  $module_name = $_POST['module'];
  $name = "_user_role_".$userid;
  $fe_id = db_insert('role')
    ->fields(array(
      'name' => $name,
    ))
    ->execute();
```

Its give below error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getcwd` gets the current working directory, i.e. the one you're executing the script from.

If you need `DRUPAL_ROOT` to refer to the root of your Drupal installation, run the script from that directory, not the one that contains your module.

If you want to execute it from the module directory, fix the paths to the includes in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has issue in first line it-self:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
```

`getcwd()` as per described on [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

> Gets the current working directory

Because of `getcwd()` your Drupal Root directory is set to your module directory and PHP isn't able to find `bootstrap.inc` and `database.inc`.